# Test Web services

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soapui

I would like to test my web services `(wsdl/soap/php)` that is exposed to my clients. ihave test it with the browsers and it's good, but when my clients test it , they have the 400 bad request error.( they test with soapui). what are the tools that i can test my web services that it exposed to my clients ? How can i verify that my server `apache` responds very good to http calls ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to see what errors are coming?

Comment: How i can use it ? i will test what ? the client say to me that he get the 400 bad request. how i can use fiddler to test my own web services and server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in an integration scenario: you've published an interface and some code over which you have no control is trying to use it.

Web Services, even simple ones, let along the full panoply of WS-* capabilities are notorious for subtle interoperability problems. These especially come from small version skew issues.

I see two fundamental philosophies here, I'm rather over-stating, to make the point:

1. You say: I publish this interface, with this WSDL, this version of the WS specs, I test it with this message and it works. You clients are responsible for creating a conformant request. I've given you a sample, it's up to to fit me. Your responsibilities are limited to producing clear working sample messages.
2. You take responsibility for conducting interoperability testing for some set of client technologies. You clearly can't test everything, but if you some key "customers" you get or build sample applications and make sure they work. You probably end up documenting "use these options when generating client code".

Either way I'd suggest you need to write test clients of your own, and as a Java developer I use JUnit for that. This get's me to step 1 above.

Comment: Thanks four your answer. the clients use soapui. my question is, if tehr server returns bad request when my client test with soapui dos mean that my web services not working ?

Comment: Well, someone is broken, it's not clear who. I don't know anything about soapui, but as far as I'm concerned it's just another client which might be using the wrong version of a spec. In this situation I would try to work with the clients, or get hold of soapui yourself and figure out whether there are options at the client end to make things work or whether your server needs to change. In doing this you are moving into accepting responsibility for interop testing.